# Uploadcare Storing Group / Files

Tags: php, file-upload, uploadcare

I am using the multifile picker instance of [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com), but have turned off "autostore". How can I store files after user clicks a submit button?

I went through the REST API, but am really new to this, so its not really clear what I need to do. An example code would be quite helpful.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Implemented the example, but am getting an internal server error. On my account I can see the images on the CDN, but none was stored. Here's my php code:

```
<?php

require_once 'Uploadcare/Api.php';
use \Uploadcare;

$public_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

$groupUUID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['groupUUID']);

$api = new Uploadcare\Api($public_key, $secret_key);
$group = $api->getGroup($groupUUID);
$group->store();

?>
```

Is there something am doing wrong?

Comment: what are you using on your backend?

Comment: I assume you are asking for the language.. if so am using php. I am really new to this... so a sample code would really help

Answer (score 1):

You have to issue a [REST API](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/rest/#group) request on your backend:

`PUT /groups/:group_id/storage/`

`:group_id` is submitted with a form by default.

For example, if you're using Uploadcare [PHP package](https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-php):

```
$group_id = $_POST['files']; // name of input field that is used by Uploadcare
$api = new Uploadcare\Api($public_key, $secret_key);
$group = $api->getGroup($group_id);
$group->store();
```